# Radio button reset function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 radios buttons.

```
<ul id='answers_ul'>
    <li>
        <input class='crossAnswer' id='c_1' name='c_1' type='checkbox'>
        <label for='c_1'></label>
        <input class='alternative-letter' id='r_1' name='r_1' type='radio' />
        <div class='answers_letters'>A</div>
        <label class='res1' for='r_1'></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class='crossAnswer' id='c_2' name='c_2' type='checkbox'>
        <label for='c_2'></label>
        <input class='alternative-letter' id='r_2' name='r_2' type='radio' />
        <div class='answers_letters'>B</div>
        <label class='res2' for='r_2'></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class='crossAnswer' id='c_3' name='c_3' type='checkbox'>
        <label for='c_3'></label>
        <input class='alternative-letter' id='r_3' name='r_3' type='radio' />
        <div class='answers_letters'>C</div>
        <label class='res3' for='r_3'></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class='crossAnswer' id='c_4' name='c_4' type='checkbox'>
        <label for='c_4'></label>
        <input class='alternative-letter' id='r_4' name='r_4' type='radio' />
        <div class='answers_letters'>D</div>
        <label class='res4' for='r_4'></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class='crossAnswer' id='c_5' name='c_5' type='checkbox'>
        <label for='c_5'></label>
        <input class='alternative-letter' id='r_5' name='r_5' type='radio' />
        <div class='answers_letters'>E</div>
        <label class='res5' for='r_5'></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The special thing about this radio buttons, is that when the user click in any of them, a svg path is append, like "filling" the radio button, but instead the previous one remains, and the new one is filled, having 2 at the time... and so on with the 5.

The problem is when I click in a second radio button, the previous svg must be removed to another svg path is append in the new one.

```
/* Deletes the previous radio svg path*/
function resetRadio(el) {
    var actualRadioName = $('input[type="radio"][name="' + el.getAttribute('name') + '"]');
    [].slice.call(actualRadioName).forEach(function(el) {
        var path = el.parentNode.querySelector('.radio-box > path');
        if (path) {
            path.parentNode.removeChild(path);
        }
    });
}


/* Button that deletes all five radio buttons svg paths*/
    jQuery('.clean_question').on('click', function(){
        selectsArr.forEach(function(obj,i) {
            [].forEach.call(obj.inputs,function(el){
                if (el.getAttribute('type') === 'radio')
                    resetRadio(el);
            })
        });
    })
```

This is an excerpt of the function that generate the svg path.

Any advice will be useful (:

Answer (score 1):

A group of radio buttons in HTML MUST all have the same value for their `name` attribute. This is what creates the mutually exclusive functionality. Your buttons all have different names and so, you can select as many of them as you'd like.

Make the `id`'s unique and have your JS code locate the buttons by those IDs, but the names must be the same.

When you do that, you can change and shorten your jQuery that locates the buttons from:

```
 var actualRadioName = $('input[type="radio"][name="' + el.getAttribute('name') + '"]');
```

to:

```
 var actualRadioName = $("#" + el.id);
```